# How do I dynamic upcast and downcast with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast

I have some code with a generic interface in which I need to cast up and down. I'm trying to convert to smart pointers now, but am running into some errors. The code below reproduces the problem. I'm using C++14, so I think this stuff is supposed to work automagically now?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int);
    *a = 5;
    std::shared_ptr<void> b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<void>(a);
    std::shared_ptr<int> c = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<int>(b);
    std::cout << *c; //should be 5
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get:

```
Error   C2680   '_Elem1 *': invalid target type for dynamic_cast    
Error   C2681   'int *': invalid expression type for dynamic_cast
```

Guessing I did something dumb in the syntax?

Comment: Dynamic cast applies to polymorphic types. Did you meant reinterpret cast?

Comment: probably? let me try

Comment: oh right. Duh. void does not live in the type hierarchy of my stuff.
(does void live in any type hierarchies?)

Comment: that's how I got this name --->

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules are the same as for dumb pointers, except you have to use `std::static_pointer_cast` and `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` instead of `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`. C++17 will introduce the counterpart for `reinterpret_cast`, but that is not needed for up- or down casts, nor for conversions from or to void.

> How do I dynamic upcast ... with smart pointers?

Conversion up in type hierarchy is implicit, so there is no need for a cast:

```
struct A{
    virtual ~A(){}
};
struct B:A{};

auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
std::shared_ptr<A> a = b;
```

> How do I dynamic ... downcast with smart pointers?

Using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` if you're unsure whether the source points to the correct type. This is only possible if the inheritance is polymorphic (i.e. the base has at least one virtual function):

```
b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a);
```

Or `std::static_pointer_cast` if you know that the type is correct:

```
b = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(a);
```

---

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<void> b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<void>(a);
> std::shared_ptr<int> c = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<int>(b);
> ```

`void` and `int` do not have an inheritance relationship so they can not be up- or down casted.

However, all pointers are implicitly convertible to a void pointer, so an implicit conversion is possible:

```
 std::shared_ptr<void> b = a;
```

And, void pointers can be static casted to the original type, so you can use `std::static_pointer_cast`:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> c = std::static_pointer_cast<int>(b);
```

Comment: For completeness, `std::shared_ptr<...>`'s aliasing constructor also works. `std::shared_ptr<int> c(b, static_cast<int*>(b.get()));`

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17, you have [`std::reinterpret_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: Wouldn't `static_pointer_cast` be enough, given one type is `void`?

Comment: Indeed, with `void` type.